# Multiple values in the same cell datatable c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

I have a DataTable and want to add several values to the same cell.

Right now I add data through this:
myDataTable.Rows[RowNumber]["ColumnName"] = "Value"

How can I add several values to the same cell in a similar manner (I want to be able to specify row number and column name)?

Edit:
What I want (made in excel)

[image]

Comment: When you say several values to the `same cell` Do you want to add comma separated values?

Comment: I added a picture to clarify! I want the values to be below each other.

Comment: These values seem to be seperated by \n. A datatable can only hold one value per cell, you can append the values like `myDataTable.Rows[RowNumber]["ColumnName"] = "Value1 " + "\nValue2" + "\nValue3"`. You can't use it to hold more than one value in a DataTable.

Comment: What If I do not know how many values I have or what they are? I have a matrix where the first column is the column number (m), second column is the row number (n) and third and four columns are the values to be added to the cell with the index n,m. There might be multiple value-pairs with the same index.

Comment: In that case I suggest you create Either a Dictionary or a List of your own defined object where you can save these values much more efficiently and do data operations on them

Comment: That's a great idea! But how do I display the values in my datatable after I have done a list of my objects?

Comment: You need the datatable to bind it to a grid I presume. If you want to use the database you can use the method I stated above, that will display your 3 values in the single cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the value of the cell to any `string` value which means that you can just create the `string` as usual and then set the cell value.

If you have a matrix of values you need to iterate through it to be able to populate the `DataTable` dynamically. Here is an example for you:

```
DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
myDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1"));
myDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col2"));
myDataTable.Rows.Add();

object[,] matrix = new object[2, 4] {
                            { 0, 0, "line1", "line2" },
                            { 0, 1, "line3", "line4" }, };

for(int i = 0; i<matrix.GetLength(0); ++i)
{
    int row = Convert.ToInt32(matrix[i, 0]);
    int column = Convert.ToInt32(matrix[i, 1]);
    myDataTable.Rows[row][column] = matrix[i, 2].ToString() + Environment.NewLine + matrix[i, 3].ToString();
}

dataGrid.ItemsSource = myDataTable.DefaultView;
```

Comment: Thank you! My matrix is inside a MWArray[] with index 0 (basically: matrix = myMWArray[0]). How can I transform it to a matrix similar to yours?

Comment: Please provide some sample code similar to the one in my answer.

Comment: The MWArray[] is returned from a matlab dll so I am not sure how to replicate it using code. I will ask a new question, and attach a picture of the value of MWArray from the debugger. Maybe it will help?

Comment: How does your "matrix" (myMWArray[0]) look like? What's the type of it? Include this.

Comment: Ok. I have included it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45079986/mwarray-to-object-c-sharp

Comment: I don't really see how these questions are related really. How to set the value of a cell in a DataTable is one thing and how to convert a Matlab array is a completely different one. This question doesn't even mention Matlab.

Comment: I agree. That is why I asked it in a new question.

Comment: So where does that leave this one?

Comment: I will take it up again when I have my MWArray[] in a native format. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Hi. I have implemented your code to my project now. It works fine after some modifications (you have to substract one from row). Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: How do you make this work when you have image (byte[]) for a cell and I want to add multiple images in single cell vertically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the special symbol for a new line and then append the strings. It may look something like this:

```
 myDataTable.Rows[RowNumber]["ColumnName"] = "Value" + "\nValue2" + "\nValue3"
```

and so on. Additionally, you can use the environment also like this:

```
 myDataTable.Rows[RowNumber]["ColumnName"] = "Value" + Environment.NewLine + "Value2"
```

Comment: What If I do not know how many values I have or what they are? I have a matrix where the first column is the column number (m), second column is the row number (n) and third and four columns are the values to be added to the cell with the index n,m. There might be multiple value-pairs with the same index.

Comment: You can add them in a list and the foreach the list like this:
for(int i = 0; i< list.count; i++) {
   myDataTable.Rows[RowNumber]["ColumnName"] += Environment.NewLine + list[i].ToString();
}

By calling ToString() you'll be sure that no matter the values, they'll be strings to append.